# iPhone 11: Subtle clicking sound and vibrational feedback on performing several actions

Tags: iphone, ios

A few days ago I noticed a silent click-sound and a subtle vibrational impulse when performing several actions on my iPhone 11.

Examples of such actions are:

- activating buttons on the control center like bluetooth or flight
  mode.
- all two-finger zooming gestures in fotos
- tapping the flashlight or camera on lock-screen (without actually activating it)
- performing the upwards 'home-swipe'

I am quite sure this behaviour wasn't there until a few days ago. I am running the latest version of iOS 13. System Haptics is turned off.

I tried resetting the phone and even did a device firmware update but the clicking is still there.

Has anyone else observed this behaviour with their iPhone 11 and might even have a solution?

Comment: Sounds like haptic feedback to me. Is the ringer OFF when this happens?

Comment: @IconDaemon Yes, the ringer is off. And it definitely feels like a haptic feedback, however way more subtle in intensity and and way more sudden to the touch than the actual haptic feedback.

Comment: @symphonic did you ever get this resolved? This started happening to me yesterday. I’ve had an iPhone 11 for months, automatic software updates turned off and suddenly started noticing subtle haptic clicks even though System Haptics is Off. Tried toggling it on and off with several restarts. I tried Reset All Settings. Updated to latest iOS version. Nothing worked.

Comment: @neildo Unfortunately not. However, there are some more people reporting this issue, e.g. https://www.reddit.com/r/ios/comments/ec287t/iphone_11_haptic_engine_creates_clicking_sound/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=ios_app&utm_name=iossmf It really seems to be a hardware thing

Comment: I actually got his resolved by installing IOS 13.4 beta. So it's a software fix.

Comment: @neildo Yes indeed, the IOS upgrade to 13.4 beta resolves the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @neildo in his comment, the issue seems to be fully resolved with iOS 13.4 beta. With the beta release installed, I have successfully checked all the actions mentioned in the question.

In order to install a public beta release, i.e. also available for non-developers, one has to sign up at https://beta.apple.com and follow the instructions.

For thouse who do not wish to have a beta release installed on their device, I'd recommend to simply wait for the final 13.4 release.

Answer (score 2):

Haptic feedback was introduced in iOS10/iPhone7 and you probably have this enabled on your phone. To disable or change the configuration, go to

```
Settings > Sounds & Haptics > System Haptics
```

Some users have reported turned this feature off doesn't stop clicking and vibrating. https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250781216. You could try re-enabling and disabling again. Also, try turning off sounds and vibrations to see what happens.

If it's still not working, you may need to contact Apple Genius or an Apple Authorized Service Provider take a look at your iPhone

Comment: No, that's not it. As stated in the question, System Haptics is already turned off.